# Creating Objects of A class of user defined size in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create objects of a class with user defined size at run time.
Like when user enter 5 it creates 5 objects.
I tried this

```
student s[num];

for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    student s[i]; // also used student s[i]=new student();
}
```

but it says `student s[num]` expression must have constant value.
So how to do this?

Comment: `std::vector<student> s(num);`

Comment: more like `ArrayList`.

Comment: vector<student> s(num); says incomplete type not allowed.

Comment: `#include <vector>`

Tricky

Comment: That's in my answer, the include is vector

Comment: Ok thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 3):

A [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) was made for just this purpose. (basically a dynamically allocated array) It has a constructor taking the number of elements to pre-allocate and construct:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<student> students(num);
```

You can loop over it as a normal array:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i)
{
  //students[i]..
}
```

Or, if you have access to C++11 use a range-based loop:

```
for(auto const& student : students)
{
  //student..
}
```

Or, it's iterators:

```
for(std::vector<student>::iterator itr = students.begin(); itr != students.end(); ++itr)
{
  //access with *itr..
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use `students.at(i)` instead of `students[i]`, in order to get run-time bounds checking.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid we're using `i < students.size()` so `[i]` must be valid.

Comment: I know, but I still just think nobody should ever use `[]` on vectors. It's a bad habit to allow it. If I was teaching C++, I would never even mention it's existence! :-)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid How exactly? bounds checking just adds pointless overhead.

Comment: I don't understand your objection. Given a choice between always using `[]` and always using `.at()`, then former will definitely introduce undefined behaviour into every non-trivial codebase. I will never believe that anybody, even the smartest person, can avoid all incorrect usage of `[]`. So the overhead is definitely not "pointless" in general

Comment: @AaronMcDaid If you use iterator, you don't have that problem, and you got even less by using range for loops. You can even use custom ranges and iterator pairs. If you absolutely need to use `.at()` and catch the error, you got serious problem in your application.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, you mentioned iterators and range-for. In both cases, the developer does not write `[]` (nor `at()`, therefore there is no issue and it is not relevant. I'm proposing to replace `[]` with `at()` - I am *not* proposing to abandon range-for. I would say instead *"if you have to use `[]` then you have an interesting problem"*. If you are using `[]`, then it means that you must be iterating in a non-standard order (otherwise, you would use iterators or range-for) - therefore you should simply use `at()` to be cautious

Comment: Well I used vectors , but it didn't worked still giving errors I'll ask them.
I'm using Visual Studio , and student is object class not of structure..

Comment: @AaronMcDaid for debugging purposes, maybe `at()` is an alternative to uncover bugs in you application easily, but if you need `at()` for your application to work, then there's bugs somewhere and you're hiding them with the `at()` function. In a well coded application, you should be able to replace every `at()` by `[]` without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, I never said I would need `at()` "for my application to work". I deliberately always leave them in my code, effectively as an assertion. When it throws and kills my program, I'm glad that it has highlighted a bug. That is preferable to undefined behaviour. Anyway, I still see no reason to generally convert `at()` to `[]` in production code

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can dynamically allocate and deallocate.  If you new[] don't forget to delete[]!

```
#include <iostream>



struct MyObj {
    float a;
    float b;
};


int main() {

    int num = 10;

    MyObj* objs = new MyObj[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        objs[i].a = i;   
        objs[i].b = i*2;
    }

    std::cout << objs[3].a << " * 2 = " << objs[3].b << std::endl;

    delete [] objs;

    return 0;
}
```

[Test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bcadceb542d0baa)

Comment: should delete all object at last or delete them as soon as they out of use???
or is there any garbage collector in C++ like C#.net???

Comment: There is no garbage collection.  If you don't delete an object you will introduce memory leaks.  You should delete the object whenever you are done with it.  Whenever makes logical sense to ensure you don't lose a block of memory by re-assigning its pointer before deleting it.